# odd behavior when when changing linkbutton text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my project, I have a datarepeater, in an updatepanel, with a linkbutton.  When the user clicks the linkbutton,  a partial post back occurs and changes the text property of the linkbutton.  The problem is: when the user clicks the same button again, even though i can physically see the new text value on the web page, when the debugger hits the event, the sender object says the text value is the old value, not the last updated.  Anyone know why?  Here is the code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbEdit" Text="Edit" EnableViewState="true"  OnClick="edit_click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("user.networkId") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

codebehind:

```
  Protected Sub edit_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
    Dim userId As String = btn.CommandArgument
    If (btn.Text = "Edit") Then
       btn.Text = "Save"
    else
       btn.Text = "Edit"
    end if
  end sub
```

Comment: To test, if you comment out the update panel, and let the page do a full postback, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Brian, yes, even when I do not use an update panel the problem still occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are rebinding your data on postback, so it is resetting your value. Then the button click event is firing, so yes you are setting `Text` correctly. But when you postback again, the text is getting reset.

Wrap your `DataBind` event in a `If Not IsPostBack`:

```
If Not IsPostBack
    'Bind your datasource
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike.  Do you mean my databind for the repeater?  The problem is, since I'm using update panels, I want to continue to bind even if it is (and it will be) a post back.

Comment: @jason Yes, for your repeater. If you add that code above, what problem do you have? In most cases, you don't need to rebind data on postback.

Comment: Mike, most actions in this user control cause the update panel to fire (causing a partial postback).  For instance, my data repeater has rows and columns (a table).  When the user clicks the column header, I sort the repeater on the postback and rebind to the repeater. If I only bind on the postback, I wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: @jason I see. Have you considered using something like [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) instead of a repeater? Or even [jQuery Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) which has offers sorting/filtering (no postback needed)? Anyway, consider adding in your repeater code into the question, so it is clear everything you are dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  What I ended up doing was just adding another linkbutton for each row.  One that says "edit" and is not hidden and the other that says "save" and is hidden. When the user click the "Edit", I just swap css styles, hiding "edit" and displaying "save".